# On a remark of John Lee concerning smooth manifolds

Tags: smooth-manifolds

In John Lee's book [Introduction to Smooth Manifolds](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ejchaidez/materials/reu/lee_smooth_manifolds.pdf), on the first page of the first chapter, he writes:

> ..."*But for more sophisticated applications it is an undue restriction to require smooth manifolds to be subsets of some ambient Euclidean space*."

But on page 134 of the same book he proves the Whitney Embedding theorem:

> Every smooth $n$-manifold with or without boundary admits a proper smooth embedding into $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$.

which seems to me to directly contradict his statement on the first page.

Question: Am I missing something?

Comment: From my point of view: if we defined a manifold to be a subset of some euclidean space, then anytime we said "this object $X$ is a manifold" we would have to exhibit a description of $X$ as a subset of some $\mathbb{R}^N$. From what I understand about Whitney's Theorem, this might not be so easy to do explicitly...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is true that each manifold can be embedded into some Euclidean space $\mathbb R^N$. In other words, each manifold is dffeomorphic to a a submanifold of a Euclidean space, and therefore one could argue that it is sufficient to develop a theory for such submanifolds. In fact, some concepts (for example, the tangent space) even allow a more intuitive access for submanifolds than for "abstract" manifolds.

However, the embedding theorem is an existence theorem which does not provide a *canonical embedding*. There are many such embeddings, and each depends on certain *choices*. A priori it is not even clear what the minimal dimension $N$ of an ambient $\mathbb R^N$ is.

Many well-known manifolds are not given as submanifold, but by other constructions. Here are some examples:

1. Projective spaces $\mathbb RP^n$ and $\mathbb CP^n$
2. More generally quotients of manifolds by group actions.
3. Grassmann manifolds and Stiefel manifolds.
4. Quotients like $[0,1]/(0 \sim 1)$.

Try to find explicit embeddings of these objects into a Euclidean space - you will see it is not easy.

Thus I completely agree to the statement that

> it is an undue restriction to require smooth manifolds to be subsets of some ambient Euclidean space.